# Laravel base64 image issue

Tags: php, laravel, base64

I am trying to store an image in base64 format in my database but when I add the $base64image variable to the $request it appears like this:

[step 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ae8j.png)

But i want to store the base64 string like this:

[step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pczUH.png)

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        try {
            $request->validate([
                'payment_file' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            ]);
            $base64image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('payment_file')->path()));
            error_log('Step 1: ' . $base64image);
            $request->merge(['payment_file' => $base64image]);
            error_log('Step 2: ' . $request->payment_file);
            Participant::create($request->all());
            return redirect()->route('participants.index')->with('success', 'Successfully created participant.');

        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return redirect()->route('participants.create')->with('error', 'The error:' . $th->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I only want to store the complete base64 String in the database, but dont know why this happens, im new in Laravel and i would apreciate your help.

Comment: Replace your payment_file variable with $base64image, As you are converting the file but you are not setting in request's variable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are trying to merge the base64 image into the request object, which is not a good practice. The request object is meant to hold the original input from the user, not the modified data.

Using Eloquent model

```
// Encode the image file into a base64 string
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('payment_file')->path()));
// Save the image using Eloquent model
$participant = new Participant();
$participant->payment_file = $image;
$participant->save();
```

Using query builder

```
// Encode the image file into a base64 string
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($request->file('payment_file')->path()));
// Save the image using query builder
DB::table('participants')->insert([
    'payment_file' => $image
]);
```

Check this link for guide:
https://mysagaventure.com/how-to-store-an-image-as-base64-in-laravel/